# Using exitnodes in torrc causes no connection in browser

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, tor

I'm using the Vidalia bundle set to client only on Windows 7. I'm using Chrome browser with the Proxy Switchy! extension. When I add:

```
ExitNodes {nz}
```

...it causes me to be unable to load any pages. If I take that line out and restart Tor, then I can access the web again. I read some things here and there that suggested I'm too restrictive with my exit nodes, so I set it to `{us}` and I still got the same problem, so it seems that any specification of `ExitNodes` will cause it to not work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly tor tries to connect to exit nodes from different countries, so that's why I think its complaining. You can add more countries, or just ignore it.

Secondly, and most important, there is no need to use an extension for that. Start chrome with this switch  **--proxy-server="socks://localhost:9050"**, and manually edit Tor's **torrc file** to add the exit nodes you want.